# Visual Studio project with database inbuilt doesn't run on other computers

Tags: sql-server, wpf, database, visual-studio-2013

The problem has been very hard for me to solve because i am still a begginer when it comes to databases, SQL and publishing your own apps with those databases.

I have made a **C# WPF Application** and added a **Service Based Database** as well as an **ADO.NET Entity Data Model** to my project. The **application runs on my computer** however when i **publish it or give the release folder to someone, the application shows up on the task manager but does not open/run**. I have tried handing out the app without the database and it works fine, so i'm sure that is the problem.

After searching trough the Internet for a long time i tried to set all my references to "copy local : True" and that did not solve the problem.

**I believe that what happens is that the database isnt saved in their pc?**

**How do i make it so that the database is added to their pc locally?**

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

connection string:

```
 <add name="TimelapseDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TimelapseModel.csdl|res://*/TimelapseModel.ssdl|res://*/TimelapseModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\TimelapseDB.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

 <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
```

Thank you for reading, and hope i made myself clear, if the information given is not clear or lacking of content, please tell me what i should give you.

Ps: I tried to add photos of my release folder and solution explorer but my reputation does not allow me to do so.

Comment: Check for the Database on the deployment machine. or Check your connection string in Enitity Framework. or how are you planning to give access to your database

Comment: the database is being used as a mean to store variables but the user doesnt need to interact with it

Comment: Sort of a Saving and Loading point for a game, if you know what i mean?

Comment: Do you mean that the Machines in which i deploy the app must have some sort of database reader like sql server express or related?